# I want to send a qrCode to an email using PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer, qr-code

This is my *qr_code.php* file:

```
require_once 'phpqrcode/qrlib.php';

function create_QrCode($name){

$path ='images/';
$file=$path.uniqid().".png";


$text=$name;

QRcode::png($text, $file);

}

?>
```

This is my *mail.php* file:

```
require('qr_code.php');


use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer; 
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception; 


require 'C:\xampp\htdocs\contact_form\vendor\autoload.php'; 



#Initialize PHPMailer
function Send_email($mailFrom,$User_name,$phone,$city,$facebook,$qrCode){

$mail= new PHPMailer();
$mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;
$mail ->isSMTP();
$mail ->SMTPAuth =true;
$mail ->SMTPDebug =3;
$mail ->SMTPSecure="tls";
$mail ->Port=587;

#Connection settings
$mail ->Host= "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail ->Username="email@gmail.com";
$mail ->Password="password";

$mailTo ='email@gmail.com';
$mail-> IsHTML(true);
$mail ->SetFrom($mailFrom,$User_name);
$mail ->addAddress($mailTo);
$mail->AddReplyTo($mailFrom, $User_name);


#Create email
$mail->Subject ='I would like to come at the party ! ';
$mail->Body ="Name: $User_name<br>
              Phone No: $phone<br>
              City: $city<br>
              Facebook: $facebook<br>
              Email id: $mailFrom<br>
              QrCode: $qrCode";




 return $mail->Send();
}
```

This is my *functionalities.php* file (where I want to send the email):

```
$qrCode=create_QrCode($name);
if(!Send_email($email,$name,$phone,$city,$facebook,$qrCode))
        {
            echo "Mail NOT SENT";

        }

    else
        {
            echo"Mail Sent !";
        }

      header('Location:redirecting_page.html');
  }
```

I have tried different modes, but I don't know how to figure it out. I know in the QRCode function, I am generating it to a file, but this is what I succesfully created until now. I know the QRCode function is the problem, but I don't know how to fix it. Can somebody please help me?

Comment: It is not smart to put your password here !

Comment: Try following a course in debugging PHP code (like [this](https://www.springest.com/lynda/debugging-php-advanced-techniques))... it will help

Comment: @Luuk I have submitted an edit for moderation, should be approved soon

Comment: Along with putting your password on here, you should censor your email address too. Don't worry, I have made adjustments to your question. I have made formatting improvements, censored Personal Information and spelling improvements.

Comment: @Julian: one can always look at the history of it..... 

Comment: @Luuk I know, that's the only down fall

Comment: @Bota Rafael may I suggest you change your password on your gmail account.

Comment: I suggest you keep your code well-formatted, even when you present it in order to ask a question for other people. Not-well-formatted code doesn't show that you care about it.

Comment: Thanks guys... i will do it, i was on a hurry so this is why i made here..... but one of you can help me with the topic ?

Comment: You can’t just put the QR image binary data Into the message body. Save it as a file and add it as an attachment. Also you’re setting SMTPSecure twice.

Comment: @Synchro i am a begginer in web dev, to be honest i do not understand very well what you are trying to explain me, i understand the concept but i do not know what i  have to do, can you help me with some code please?

Comment: What's the exact problem with the given code? Anything not working?

Comment: @NicoHaase yes it works almost perfectly, but i want to attach the created qr code to the body of email where i send the email in function mail, and it does not work... i do not know how to figure that out...